# Running a jar file (within a loop) in a script with redirected output

Tags: java, bash, batch-file

I'm trying to run a jar file multiple times (in a loop) and redirect its output to a file (using the append >> operator). I'm running, and must keep using, Windows 7. I tried doing this in a windows batch file and ran into the problem below so I installed Cygwin to make use of the bash script. My script is below:

```
for i in {1..10..1}
  do
    echo "Run $i"
    java -jar myjar.jar -cl >> runresults.txt
    echo "Sleeping..."
    sleep 60
    echo "Awake!"
done
```

The problem: The script (Windows batch or Cygwin bash) runs only some iterations before hanging up (usually never more than 3). There's no error given. I added the sleep command to ensure that the prior iteration had time to release any locks prior to any attempt to make the next run. I've increased the sleep time to 200+ seconds and the behavior is still the same. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I think there is a bug in your .jar file probably.

Comment: LtWorf thanks for your reply.  The jar file has been in use for some time and works as designed outside the shell script.

Comment: Anyway your for only goes from 1 to 10.. what's that extra ..1 after the 10?

Comment: That's the step size (which is admittedly unnecessary is this case).

Comment: Try a script that has the jar invocation repeated 10 times right in a row.  Drop some echo statements in between to see where it's at.  If it can't make it through that, then it's likely the jar file that's got the problem.

Comment: What line is the script "hanging up" at?  Is java still running?  What happens if you remove the redirection - does it run all 10 times without hanging?

Comment: Perhaps your jar sometimes returns a non-zero exit code and you have `errexit` set (e.g. `set -e` or `set -o errexit` in your script or profile)? This makes a script exit immediately if a command exits with an error. Try `set +e` above the loop to disable it and print `$?` after the java app to confirm.

Comment: A effective way to debug scripts is to turn on the xtrace option (set -x), this will show each line as it's executed, and therefore show you were it's hanging up.  But given the script, I'd assume also that the java command isn't returning in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ ! -f runresults.txt ]; then
    touch runresults.txt
fi

for i in {1..10}
  do
    echo "Running... $i"
    java -jar myjar.jar >> runresults.txt &
    echo "Sleeping 2 seconds..."
    sleep 2
done
```